# WCF POST JSON HttpWebRequest to a restful service does not work properly

Tags: c#, json, rest, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a WCF POST call to a restful service but the object that I provide does not seem to be deserialized properly by the server and is set to null.

WCF Service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat =      WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "BuildItems")]
void Upgrade(BuildItem item);
```

Client code:

```
public void Upgrade(BuildItem item)
{
    string uri = string.Format(@"http://localhost:9001/AFMServer" + "/BuildItems");
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    request.GetResponse();
}
```

The service gets called property server side, but the BuildItem is null.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT - found the problem. Since I am using "Wrapped" in need to wrap the object with the parameter name:

{"item":{"CompletionDateTime":"/Date(-62135596800000+0000)/","Id":0,"ItemId":7,"ItemType":0}}

HTH

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same but the GetRequestStream is showing an error. It doesn't recognise it.